# List in Ruby gem cli

Tags: ruby

I am making a ruby cli that outputs a list of game deals scraped from a site.

The list prints out promptly using

```
def games_sales
  Deal.all.each_with_index do |deal, index|
    puts "#{index + 1}.  #{deal.title}"
  end 

  puts "What game do you want to see?"
  input = gets.strip

  game_selection(input.to_i)
end
```

My problem comes when asking the user to select an item from the list.

```
def game_selection(input) 
  deal = Deal.find_by_index(input)
  #binding.pry
  deal.each do |deal| 
    puts "#{deal.index}"
    puts " Name: #{deal.title}" 
    puts " Price: #{deal.price}"
    puts " Store: #{deal.store}"
    puts " Expiration: #{deal.expiration}"
  end 
  deal
end
```

It returns the int input but only the first item on the list every time.

I forgot my find_by_index method:

```
def self.find_by_index(input)
  all.select do |deal|

  end
end
```

which is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if I got your question right and if you're using Rails, but `Deals.all` let me think of this.

I had to replace Deals.all with DEALS for testing as I haven't got a rails app running. So I used an Array of OpenStructs to fake your Model result.

```
# this fakes Deals.all
require 'ostruct' 
DEALS = [
    # add any more properties the same way as title, separated by comma
    OpenStruct.new(title: 123),
    OpenStruct.new(title: 456) 
]

def games_sales
  DEALS.each_with_index do |deal, index|
    puts "#{index + 1}.  #{deal.title}"
  end 

  puts "What game do you want to see?"
  input = gets.strip

  game_selection(input.to_i)
end

def game_selection(input) 
  deal = DEALS.at(input-1)
  p deal[:title]
end 

def self.find_by_index(input)
  all.select do |deal|
    deal.index == input
  end
end 

games_sales
```

Result when choosing `1` is `123`, choosing `2` you'll get `456`, due to `p deal[:title]` above in the code.

I think your find_by_index need to get the right index and in my example I had to use `at(index)` as `at(input-1)` in order to get the right result.

I really hope this helps somehow and I suggest that you add the expected result to your question, in case my answer does not help you.

Comment: I see ok. I updated this a little bit before I saw your response. when I choose an item from this list right now I receive info for every object not just the selection. Thank you for your response I appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, then you need a condition in find_by_index, e.g. `deal.index == input` and you should not loop over the deals using each in game_selection but only output the deal attributes (as you do in the loop).

Comment: Let me know if you need more input.